# Search for a text containing backslash in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a mysql table with 2 entries (id ,title) (int, text)

A row of dummy data in the table looks like

```
id title
1  apple\"apple
```

My query intends to do a search on the field title

```
select * from table1 where title='apple\"apple';
```

I also tried using

```
select * from table1 where title like('apple\"apple');
```

The above query did not seem to work as well.

Both queries are returning an empty sets. Is it not possible to search for a string that has backslash in it?

PS :: The \ is added to the DB as part of escaping the double quotes.

Comment: Please post a table schema

Answer (score 0):

Sure? It works as expected.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE MyTbl (id INT, title TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO MyTbl VALUES(1,'apple "apple');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTbl;
+------+-------------+
| id   | title       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | apple"apple |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title = 'apple \"apple';
+------+-------------+
| id   | title       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | apple"apple |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title like('apple \"apple');
+------+-------------+
| id   | title       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | apple"apple |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe Is it something related to the space character?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title = 'apple\"apple';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title = 'apple \"apple';
+------+--------------+
| id   | title        |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | apple "apple |
+------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What about running this command? What It returns for you?

```
mysql> SELECT @NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES;
+----------------------------------------------+
| @NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                         |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How is this an answer when the OP has already tried this and returns null for them?

Comment: It means It doesn't return null for everybody! Probably Something is wrong with settings, but not code itself.

Comment: SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title = 'apple\"apple'; 
This query is still not working for me. 
I need to run SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title = 'apple%\"apple'; 
or SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE title = 'apple\\\\"apple';  to get results

Comment: @Daffodil Maybe space character is missing. Check my updated post at the bottom.